# Acessing a database a single time in php with multiple files

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am trying to modify a page from `php` based on form input. The modification depends on the value of a `mysql` database query. Consider the sample file:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="a.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="" method="post">
      UserName: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
      <?php if(isset($_POST)) {
            $user=readUserNameFromDataBase($_POST["name"]);
            if (empty($user)) { echo "Invalid user name!<br>"; }
          }
    ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

I also need to modify the css of the page. That is done from the included `css` file `a.php`:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
body {
  background: <?php  if(isset($_POST)) {
              $user=readUserNameFromDataBase($_POST["name"]);
              if (empty($user)) { echo "#ff0000;"; }
              else { echo "#00ff00;"; }
             } else { echo "#00ff00;"; } ?>
}
```

It seems like overkill to access the database twice here, so my question is:

Is it possible access the database once, defining a variable `$user` and then later from the different `php` tags access this variable as a superglobal or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can put in a session variable, that will allow you to keep it there for the entire visit of that person on the site. However, if it's only one page you're wanting to keep it on, just reference the `$user` variable. If that's not set, then get it from your DB.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (!isset($user))
    {
        $user = readUserNameFromDataBase($_POST["name"]);
    }
    if (empty($user)) { /* .. your code .. */ }
}
```

By the way, checking if $_POST is set is a rather bad idea. Since it's a superglobal, it's always set.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like I got another problem. In the css file the statement `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` seems to never be true. How can I check this from within the `css` file also?

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't. You will want to put a class on the `<body>` attribute based on the user you get (like `admin`) and use that to change the background color. CSS has no knowledge of a user, nor it should.